# How to enable disable field with radio in looping

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, loops

I have some problem in looping to make an action if radio with value = 1 then input field is enable.

here is my code, but imagine that the field and radio in a looping :

```
<form name="form" id="form">
<table>
    <?php
        $arr = array(0=>"Disable", 1=>"Enable");
        for($i=0; $i<5; $i++):
    ?>
            <tr>
                <td><input type='text' name='input[]' id='input'></td>
                <td>
                <?php
                    foreach($arr as $key=>$val):
                ?>
                        <input type='radio' name='ans[<?php echo $i; ?>]' id='ans' value='<?php echo $key; ?>' onClick="d_e(this.value)"> <?php echo $val; 
              <?php endforeach; ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
  <?php endfor; ?>
</table>
```

```
<script>
    function d_e(id){
        var i = document.form.input;
        for(var c=0; c<i.length; c++){
            if(id==1){
                i[c].disabled = false;
            }else{
                i[c].disabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: for disable the field just write disable attribute and for enable write empty string, this should work.

Comment: but when i select disable, then all field input will be disable

Comment: so you want to just disable one of them?

Comment: yes, disable when his radio is checked

Comment: i would create two radio button, one for enable another one for disable.

Comment: Yes, but if you want to use checkbox only for enable. not bad. when unchecked then field will disable

Comment: so why won't you use checkbox instead of radio

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153647/discussion-between-max-and-muh-fadly-sangadji).